# Unable to retrieve EngineVersion for aurora_postgresql in describe_db_engine_versions using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running boto3 to read the EngineVersion. It works for most of the RDS engines except aurora-postgresql which I am not sure why.

Here is the code to aurora-mysql and I got the EngineVersion.

```
client = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_engine_versions(
    DBParameterGroupFamily='aurora-mysql5.7'
    DefaultOnly=True,
    Engine='aurora-mysql'
    ListSupportedCharacterSets=False,
)
a=response['DBEngineVersions'][0]['EngineVersion']
print(a)
```

This code looks for aurora-postgresql and it doesn't return.

```
client = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_engine_versions(
    DBParameterGroupFamily='aurora-postgresql9.6',
    DefaultOnly=True,
    Engine='aurora-postgresql',
    ListSupportedCharacterSets=False,
)
a=response['DBEngineVersions'][0]['EngineVersion']
print(a)
```

I tried with mysql, postgres and Oracle and they all return proper EngineVersion. Anyone knows what I have done wrong?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, here's a variant of your lookup that seems to work ok:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds')

for engine in ['aurora-postgresql', 'aurora-mysql', 'oracle-ee']:
  response = client.describe_db_engine_versions(Engine=engine)
  print "%s: %s" % (engine, [x['EngineVersion'] for x in response['DBEngineVersions']])
```

As for what you are doing wrong, or exactly why your second call doesn't return anything ... I don't have a better explanation than simply misbehavior or an outright bug in this AWS API. If I run:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions  --engine='aurora-postgresql'
```

I get back several results with:

> "DBParameterGroupFamily": "aurora-postgresql9.6",

but, as you noticed, when you search for that exact DBParameterGroupFamily, like so:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions  --db-parameter-group-family='aurora-postgresql9.6'
```

no results are returned. Maybe AWS would be able to explain this as a feature somehow, but it looks like a bug to me too.